# How can I embed an Editor just like those in StackExchange Q&A in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes

I am new to Drupal.

I want to embed an editor in my content, body nodes so that I can do different editing when I add a new content. (i.e., bold , hyperlink, list) etc.

Is it possible to do that? Any module is available?

Comment: If you're wondering about the specific editor that StackExchange sites use, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26412/what-wysiwyg-editor-is-stack-overflow-using

Comment: but for this wmd editor, is it supported in drupal7? I found that I can't make install inside WYSIWYG module

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that wmd editor is not available as a Drupal module that I know of.  Hence I posted it as a comment, just for an FYI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few.  One of the most popular editor modules is [WYSIWYG](http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) which allows you to choose which JavaScript library you want to use, or there are more specific modules such as the [CKEditor module](http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor)

Comment: Basically, what I want is a editor that provide a good Preview functionality, there are a lot of editor, which one you recommend?

Comment: While using a WYSIWYG editor, everything typed in, formatted etc will look the same once saved (hence "What You See Is What You Get"), there really is no need for a live preview.  As for choosing an editor it is really personal preference.  You should try a few out and see which you like the best. Some support more options than others

Comment: Thanks I will check with those modules. But a preview system is still good, I think, personally, well, SO also have a preview system, that make sure what I type is what I see :p